# Please welcome your new pro tem moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators, announcements

I'm Pops, a Community Manager at Stack Exchange. Though it saddens me to say it, not just one but two of your existing moderators are leaving the team at this time. Over the past week, I've been working on finding a replacement, and I'm happy to announce that someone with experience and the support of the rest of the team has answered the call to be your new pro tem mod:

[image: Ankit Sharma]

Please join me in thanking cheenbabes and senshin for their service and welcoming Ankit Sharma!

Answer (score 9):

I am happy to be in the team as I am already in love with this site. Really thankful to you as well as the team and the rest of the people for the support I got from them.

I am going to contribute here as much as I can and will try to incorporate all of my previous experiences and knowledge. Anyone can feel free to ping me in our [Hinduism chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism), even when I am not there.

Finally, I want to thank [cheenbabes](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/39/cheenbabes) and [senshin](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/13/senshin) for their contributions for this site. I hope they stayed longer as moderator here, but everyone had their reasons and we should respect that. Their work was really appreciable.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: @iammilind Thanks.

Comment: Grats, welcome to mod team.

Comment: @Mr.Alien thanks, will love to work with you guys.